# Should we use Schedulers in RxJava everytime

Tags: rx-java

I am new to RxJava and currently using version 1 of RxJava. 
My use case is like I have to make one rest API call(using rest template). So is it the better idea to use Schedulers.computation() or any scheduler every time in this situation.

My classes are like

> **SampleController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public DeferredResult<List<Response>> getresponse() {
        DeferredResult<List<Response>> response = new DeferredResult<>();
            service
              .fetchJson()
              .subscribe(result -> response.setResult(result));
        return response;
    }
```

> **Service.java**

```
@Override
    public Observable<List<Response>> fetchJson() {
        Observable<List<Response>> list = Observable.<List<Response>>create(
                subscriber -> subscriber.onNext(this.invokeRestCall(APIURL)))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor));*/
        return list;
    }

    private List<Response> invokeRestCall(String APIURL) {  

        Response[] responses = restTemplate.getForObject(APIURL, Response[].class);
        return Arrays.stream(responses).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Here I am using Schedulers to initiate new thread. But again i am using deffered result for instant response and spring will put it in queue and once response is there it will pass on the response.

So should i avoid Schedulers and make it run on subscriber thread only because i have only one rest call ?

Please suggest as i am really new to this.

Answer (score 0):

RxJava gives you critical control over when and where your computations get done. Using explicitly-provided schedulers to control certain phases of observer chains provides thread-safety and ensures the data is where you need it to be when you want it there.

That being said, the `Schedulers` static class methods return globally known schedulers. When you are testing, or when you want to re-use your code in a different context, the use of globals is a severe hindrance.

I suggest that you pass in the scheduler(s) you want to use, perhaps in the constructor for your service class. This is sometimes called dependency injection, and it makes your code more portable, more testable and, ultimately, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Rx is synchronous and everything works on the same thread, *unless* you assign the execution ('.subscribeOn') and/or observing ('.observeOn') to schedulers operating on other threads.

So it really depends on the task at hand. Retrofit for instance is using its own scheduler. UI may only be mutated from Android main thread. For unit tests, it is convenient to use schedulers where you can advance time manually.

Comment: So lets say if i am making only one rest call in observable and using using DeferredResult as reponse type for a api in controller. By using DeferredResult main thread will not wait for the response of the rest call, instead it will return the response immediately and once response arrived.it will push it in the queue.Thats what my understanding is. So just want to know if we have only one rest call in observable, should we use scheduler becasue using DeferredRsult main thread is not waiting any more.So in this case we should not use scheduler and go with normal observable. Please suggest ?

Comment: Not sure whether you need to do anything about execution (i.e. subscribeOn), but perhaps it is prudent to observe on main thread. Depends on how you deal with response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce `multithreading` into your cascade of Observable operators, you can do so by instructing those operators (or particular Observables) to operate on particular Schedulers.

Comment: So in my example above... creating extra thread will be useful or overhead or i should keep it on the subscriber thread only(bcz there is only one operation) ?